# Chrome Javascript Console does not print any expression or variable inspection result

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I reinstall Chrome (version 52.0.2743.116 m). It has the default google docs extensions enabled.

When I write expressions in the developer tool Javascript Console, Console does not print anything. It only prints the next empty line to write the next sentence.

For example, I wrote:

> 1 + 1
>
> window
>
> Date.now()

but nothing is printed

If I debug the code, the variable inspector of the Source panel shows all correctly and the Watch subpanel can process all expressions.

Any idea?

Comment: Works for me without google docs extensions

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of console outputs?

Comment: This is very similar to the behavior I get when I do a long-running task in the console like `i=0; while(i<5000000000) i++`. (i.e., I can type in new expressions, but nothing is evaluated) I don't know if that's your issue here, though.

Comment: Do you have any other "develop plugin" extension installed? They conflict sometimes...